# Error message states "Invalid column name," yet it seems fine?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a stored procedure named `spInsertWorkRecord`. Before inserting the record, it tests for the existence of the `EmpID` in the `EmpData` table. If the `EmpID` exists, the record will be inserted. If the `EmpID` does not exist, a custom `RAISERROR` message will be displayed.

Would the `EmpData` table be a temporary table? Why are there red squiggly lines under the `EmpId` and `FROM` in this line of code?

```
IF EmpID FROM #EmpData EXISTS
```

I get an error message stating that the `EmpData` is an

> Invalid column name

and that it the `FROM` is an

> Incorrect syntax near 'FROM'

The code statement seems right to me and I do have the `EmpData` table created so I am wondering why it keeps having the error message? This is my current code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('spInsertWorkRecord') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE spInsertWordRecord;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertWorkRecord
    @PayRate money, 
    @Salaried bit, 
    @StartDate smalldatetime, 
    @EndDate smalldatetime,
    @COLA bit, 
    @EmpID int, 
    @DeptID int
AS
    SELECT EmpID 
    FROM EmpData

    IF OBJECT_ID(EmpData) IS NOT NULL -- Should this have been a temporary table?
        DROP TABLE EmpData;

    IF EmpID FROM #EmpData EXISTS

    BEGIN TRY -- Defines the start of a TRY statement block.
        /* Inserts @Payrate, and @Salaried, @StartDate, @EndDAte, @Cola, @EmpID, and @DeptID
           into the Work table before it prints out "New Pay period added." */
        INSERT INTO Work
        VALUES (@PayRate, @Salaried, @StartDate, @EndDate, @Cola, @EmpID, @DeptID);
    END TRY -- Ends the TRY statement block.
    /* If there are errors or other inconsistencies, then this CATCH block outputs error messages. */
    BEGIN CATCH -- Defines the start of a CATCH statement block.
        /* If those values exist, then create a RAISERROR message. */
        RAISERROR ('Not a valid EmployeeID', 11, 1);
    END CATCH; -- Ends the CATCH statement block.

    /* A TRY statement block that inserts 32.30, 0, 11/5/2014, NULL, 0, 83, and 9 into the Work table. */
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO Work
        VALUES (21.20, 0, '11/5/2014', NULL, 0, 83, 9);
    END TRY -- Ends the TRY statement block.
    /* If there are errors or other inconsistencies, then this CATCH block outputs error messages. */
    BEGIN CATCH -- Defines the start of a CATCH statement block.
        PRINT 'An error occurred.';
        PRINT 'Message: ' +  CONVERT(varchar, ERROR_SEVERITY(), 11) + CONVERT(varchar, ERROR_NUMBER(), 1) + ': ' +  ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH;
```

Comment: You are eating and converting errors - that is not a wise error-handling approach. Think carefully about your goal and how you (or anyone else) will debug errors in a live system when all you get is "Not a valid EmployeeID". You don't nee a try/catch block for each statement generally. And you should not be using PRINT to communicate with an application in a production system.

Comment: `DROP PROCEDURE spInsertWordRecord;` That is not the name of the procedure you create.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be what you need:

`IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM EmpData WHERE EmpID = @empID) BEGIN --Do you insert here END ELSE BEGIN --Raise your error here END`

EmpData is almost certainly a permanent table, so shouldn't be temporary. You are checking if the employee exists before entering a record in the work table. That data should be permanent.